# $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = 0$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = a$

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function defined on $(0,1]$. Define a  subset $I \subseteq \Bbb R$ as follows: $a\in I$ if and only if there exists a sequence in the interval $(0,1]$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n =0$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = a.$

> I want to show that in general, if $I$ is nonempty, then it is a connected closed set.

When $f(x)$ is $\sin1/x$, I think $I=[-1,1]$ by seeing graph. (I was taught this by Elliot G.). More precisely,by taking $x_n＝1/2nπ ,y_n＝1/（２nπ＋1/2）$,we can check $1,-1∈I$.In the same way, for arcitrary a∈[-1,1],we just need to let $x_n＝1/（２πn＋arcsina）$.
But in general, I cannot show $I$ is connected closed set in real line.
According to Michael, we just need to show $ let a,b∈I,a＜b,c∈（a,b）,
then, c∈I$. I understand that, but I don't know how to apply intermediate value theorem in this situation. Thank you.

Comment: The example $f(x) = \sin(1/x)$ is a classic example where $I$ contains more than one point.

Comment: why? I think when xn→０、1/xn→∞、so sin1/xn does not converge.

Comment: You should try finding a sequence $x_n\rightarrow 0$ for which $f(x_n)=-1$ for all $n\in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$. Then try finding a sequence $y_n \rightarrow 0$ for which $f(y_n)=0$ for all $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$.

Comment: In that case $I=[-1,1]$.  @bellow Look at a graph of $\sin(1/x)$ and you will see why.

Comment: I see your edits.  For intuition, you would do well to continue finding the $x_n$ and $y_n$ as in my second comment for the special case $f(x) = \sin(1/x)$.  For the general problem you want to show that if $a\in I$ and $b\in I$, where $a<b$, and if $c \in (a,b)$, then $c \in I$.  You would use the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: $I$ being "a closed interval" may be tricky.  If, for instance, $f(x) = \sin(1/x)/x$, $I$ is the entire real line.  (The entire real line is closed in itself, but very few people are thinking of this technicality when they say "closed interval".)

Comment: @Michael  I want you to write in answer form. I really want to read your answer more detailed, my teacher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of lim sup and lim inf, there are sequences $u_k\to0$ and $v_k\to0$ such that $\lim_{k\to\infty}f(u_k)=\lim\sup_{x\to0}f(x)$ and $\lim_{k\to\infty}f(v_k)=\lim\inf_{x\to0}f(x)$ and any other limit that $f(x_k)$ takes as $x_k\to0$ must lie between these two values. We need only show that *every* value between the lim sup and lim inf is the limit of some sequence $x_k\to0$.

By passing to subsequences if necessary, we can assume that $f(u_1)\le f(u_2)\le f(u_3)\le\cdots$, $f(v_1)\ge v(v_2)\ge f(v_3)\ge\cdots$, and $1\ge v_1\gt u_1\gt v_2\gt u_2\gt v_3\gt u_3\gt\cdots$.  Now if $a$ is strictly between the lim inf and lim sup, then for some $\epsilon\gt0$, the interval $[a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon]$ is as well. It follows that $f(v_k)\lt a-\epsilon$ and $f(u_k)\gt a+\epsilon$ for all $k\gt N$, for some $N$. By the Intermediate Value Theorem, each interval $(u_k,v_k)$, for $k\gt N$, contains a point $x_k$ for which $f(x_k)=a$ (since $f$ is assumed to be continuous). Clearly $x_k\to0$ and $\lim_{k\to\infty}f(x_k)=a$.

Remark: The only way the closed connected set $I$ can be empty is if the lim sup and lim inf are both $\infty$ or both $-\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

For connectivity, apply the intermediate value theorem. Suppose that $x, y \in I$ and without loss of generality take $x < y$. Then there exist monotonically decreasing sequences $x_n$, $y_n$ converging to $0$ so $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = x$, $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}f(y_n) = y$. Using terms from these sequences, one can form a decreasing sequence $z_n \to 0$ so that $\lim\limits_{k \to \infty}f(z_{2k}) = x$ and $\lim\limits_{k \to \infty}f(z_{2k+1}) = y$. Now fix $\alpha$ so $x < \alpha < y$. We can find a sequence of real numbers $\alpha_k$ so that for all $k$, $f(z_{2k}) \leq \alpha_k \leq f(z_{2k+1})$ and $\lim\limits_{k \to \infty}\alpha_k = \alpha$. Continuity of $f$ and the intermediate value theorem provide us a decreasing sequence $\tilde{z}_k \to 0$ so $f(\tilde{z}_k) = \alpha_k$. We conclude that $\alpha \in I$, so $I$ is connected.

To see that $I$ is closed, take $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and a sequence $\alpha_k$ in $ I$ converging to $\alpha$. By the definition, we get decreasing sequences $x_{k, n}$ so that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x_{k,n} = 0$ for all $k$ and $\lim\limits_{k \to \infty } f(x_{k,n}) = \alpha_k$ for all $k$. With this one can inductively construct a decreasing sequence $x_k$ converging to $0$ so that $|f(x_k) - \alpha_k| < \frac{1}{k}$. One can then see that $\lim\limits_{k \to \infty}f(x_k) = \alpha$, so $\alpha \in I$ completing the proof.

One should note that $I$ need not be a closed interval. The function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x} \sin(1/x)$ is an example where $I = \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: sorry, the third line from the top, limfn（x）＝x、and forth line, limf（z2k +１）＝y？

Comment: Good catch - thanks!

Comment: Could you explain me more detail how did you applied intermediate value theorem?

Comment: So $f(z_{2k}) \leq \alpha_k \leq f(z_{2k+1})$ and $z_{2k} < z_{2k+1}$. The intermediate value theorem gives a $\tilde{z}_k$ so $z_{2k} \leq \tilde{z}_k \leq z_{2k+1}$ with $f(z_k) = \alpha_k$. (There was a typo in the application in my answer which has been fixed)

Comment: Forth line from the bottom, could you explain me how did you inductively constructed xk?

Comment: Take $x_1$ anything from $(x_{1,k})$ so $|f(x_1) - \alpha_1| < 1$. Once $x_{k}$ is chosen, as $x_{n,k} \to 0$ and $f(x_{n,k}) \to \alpha_k$, there is an element of this sequence, say labelled $x_{k+1}$, so $ 0 < x_{k+1}< 1/k$ and $x_{k+1} < x_k$ and $|f(x_k) - \alpha_k| < 1/k$.

Answer (score -1):

Assume $a \notin I$.  Then $\exists \varepsilon \gt 0$ such that $\{ x \mid \vert f(x) - a \vert \lt \varepsilon \}$ is finite.  But then there must be an open ball around $a$ for which the same statement is true:  If $\vert y - a \vert \lt \frac {\varepsilon}{2}$, then $\{ x \mid \vert f(x) - y \vert \lt \frac {\varepsilon}{2} \} \subseteq \{ x \mid \vert f(x) - a \vert \lt \varepsilon \}$ is finite (because it's a subset of a finite set), so also $y \notin I$.  Therefore $\Bbb R \setminus I$ is open, and $I$ is closed.

Alex Nolte's proof demonstrates that $I$ must be connected.

Comment: Why the downvote?  Did I get something wrong?